# Add rows to pandas data frame at the end of a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to add rows in data frame as part of a loop.

The programme loops through URLs and extracts data in a data frame format

```
for id in game_ids:
    df_team_final = []
    df_player_final = []
    url = 'https://www.fibalivestats.com/data/' + id + '/data.json'
    content = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(content.content)
```

At the end of the loop I have used concat to merge the two df of the away / home teams (and players)

```
    team_full = pd.concat([df_home_team, df_away_team])
    player_full = pd.concat([df_home_player_merge, df_away_player_merge])
```

Outside the loop I have then programmed to save as Excel

```
# #if cant find it, create new spread sheet
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Box Data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
team_full.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Team Stats', index=False)
player_full.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Player Stats', index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

As as I am looping through a number of web pages I need to update the df as I go, obviously in the current format I am just overwriting the first url with the second loop

What is the best way to append or add to the dataframe at the end of the loop?

Thank you

Comment: can you first collect all the data and then write it to excel at once?

Comment: What about defining a full_df and appending each player_full to it at the end of each loop? At last write full_df to excel.

Comment: @politicalscientist, that's what I am aiming to do, but at the moment it just over writes the previous loop as haven't worked out how to add rows to a data frame.

Comment: @AliKhatami I want to keep the player and team stats separate at this point. Currently at the end of the loop I have the two individual data frame (team = away team and full team; player = home and away players), but as mentioned above, it get overwritten when the next loop occurs as I think I just lose the previous df. So need a away it will save to df and add new rows as I go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give here only a bare outline as we don't see the full code.

I assume you don't append scraped data to some sort of a container, so it gets lost after the next iteration.

```py
# empty lists outside of loop to store data
df_team_final = []
df_player_final = []

for id in game_ids:
    url = 'https://www.fibalivestats.com/data/' + id + '/data.json'
    content = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(content.content)

    # create dataframes that you need
    # df_home_team, df_away_team etc
    # and append data to containers

    team_full = pd.concat([df_home_team, df_away_team])
    player_full = pd.concat([df_home_player_merge, df_away_player_merge])

    df_team_final.append(team_full)
    df_player_final.append(player_full )
```

---

Now that you stored dataframes as lists, you can merge them with `pandas.concat`

```py
# outside of the loop
team_full = pd.concat(df_team_final)
player_full = pd.concat(df_player_final)
```

and save at once:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Box Data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
team_full.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Team Stats', index=False)
player_full.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Player Stats', index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

---

## Edit

From the file you shared I see that you added containers inside of a loop:

[image]

But you should put them before the loop begins:

```
# initialize them here
df_team_final = []
df_player_final = []
for id in game_ids:
```

Comment: Its still only showing the last data frame. I have checked the loop in isolation and if I add a simple print statement at the loop it prints the dfs from the two urls, so thinking the code must be ok and something to fo with the way I am trying to append? Here is my full code:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dLR2vaxdD6RBIeUfJMPyhLuWZxRfPGBe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you you very much! Makes complete sense now and won't make that mistake again! Thanks for taking the time to look through the code for a second time